# Scheme - Is there a way to set an expression as the pred in the remf* functionality?

Tags: scheme, lisp

As part of an assignment, I need to create my own version Scheme's filter function. I am at a point where my code is able to pick out which values to print, based on a specific condition, but for values that don't, in their place is `#<void>`. I've been looking through Scheme documentation and I think my best bet to drop such values is to use `remf*` but I want to be able to input a specific expression in the `pred` field. The interpreter I am using keeps giving me errors, so I would like to know if it is possible to use `remf*` for what I want to achieve or if I should look at another function

My own filter function so far and its return:

```
(define (sort max lst)
    (map (λ (x) (cond[(> x max) x])) lst))

'(#<void> #<void> 6 7)
```

My separate test code with `remf*`

```
(remf* (= car 2) '(1 2 3 4))
```

I'm new to Scheme, so if there is a better function I can use please let me know and I will look up its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely do not want to use `remf*`.  Or, for that matter, `map`.  Instead think about what filtering a list means, which is roughly this.

To filter a list with a predicate:

1. if the list is empty the result is the empty list;
2. otherwise the list has a first element and some other elements –

   1. if the predicate is true for the first element, the result is a list which is the first element consed onto the result of filtering the other elements (do you have a handy function to do that?  not quite yet, perhaps),
   2. otherwise it is the result of filtering the other elements;
3. ... profit.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! I have something that works!

Answer (score 0):

> The interpreter I am using keeps giving me errors

For future questions, please add the relevant errors to help with debugging.

> ```
> (remf* (= car 2) '(1 2 3 4))
> ```

The predicate should be a procedure, but here you are giving an expression directly. You should build a function, as was done in your `map` example:

```
(remf* (lambda (v) (= v 2))
       '(1 2 3 4))
```

Instead of using `map`, which always returns a list of the same size as the input list, you can try using `fold-right`, which *folds* a list into an aggregate value (catamorphism). It accepts a base value, here below the empty list `'()`, and a procedure which accepts the current `value` in the list and the current aggregated result, here `result-list`.

Here, when `value` is equal to 2, the given `result-list` is returned as-is.
Otherwise, the current value is added in front of `result-list`, to build the new aggregated value. So the example below removes the 2 from the list.

```
(fold-right (lambda (value result-list) 
               (if (= value 2) 
                   result-list
                   (cons value result-list)))
            '() 
            '(1 2 3 4 4 2))
=> (4 4 3 1)
```

In order to build your own *filter* function, you can accept a function `f` which serves as a predicate, and instead of comparing `value` with 2, you would call `(f value)` to see if the element should be retained or not.